# Error:--FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -12910. 49152 bytes

Tags: objective-c

I am getting above error when I run program in device and it crashes,while it works fine in simulator,I am loading images using asset library and displaying in scroll view.
Here is my code::

-

```
(void)usingAssets{
    x=0;
    y=0;
    w=320;
    h=460;

   void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

        if(result != NULL) {
             [app hideLoading];



            [assets addObject:result];
            NSLog(@"assets count: %i", assets.count);


            NSString *assetType = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];
            if ([assetType isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
                NSLog(@"Photo Asset");


                [self success];
            }


        }
        else {
            [app hideLoading];
            NSLog(@"AssetEnum: result nil or end of list");
        }



   };






    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {


        if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"GroupEnum: group nil or end of list..");
        }





        [assets retain];



    };


    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos 
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error.description);
                         }];
   // [library release];




    isVisited=YES;
}



-(void)success{




    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){


        for(int i=0;i<[assets count];i++){
            asset = [assets objectAtIndex:i];
            UIImage *images = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage] scale:1.0 orientation:[[asset valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] intValue]];
                       imageview =[[UIImageView alloc]init];

            imageview.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

            [imageview setImage:images];

            [scrollview addSubview:imageview];

            x = x  + w ;

        }





    });


}



#pragma mark:----scroll view methods



- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint scrollOffset=scrollView.contentOffset;


    ///at any time, it will have only 3 pages loaded- previous, current and next
    if(pageno < ((int)scrollOffset.x/320))
    {
        //unload
        if(pageno>1)[self unloadPreviousPage:pageno-2];

        //load the next page
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:((int)scrollOffset.x/320)+1];
    }
    else if(pageno > ((int)scrollOffset.x/320))
    {
        //unload
        if(pageno<(kNumberOfPages-2))[self unloadPreviousPage:pageno+2];

        //load back the previous page
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:((int)scrollOffset.x/320)-1];
    }

    pageno=scrollOffset.x/320;
}

-(void)unloadPreviousPage:(int)index
{



    for(int i=index*4;i<(index+1)*4;i++)
    {
        [[scrollview viewWithTag:i+1] removeFromSuperview];

    }


}







- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    if (page < 0)
        return;
    if (page >= kNumberOfPages)
        return;

        pageno=page;
    pgControl.currentPage=pageno-1;

    if(isVisited==NO){
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(usingAssets) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (ALAsset* a in assets){
        NSLog(@"Item in asset");
    }

    }


}
```

Please correct me where I am going wrong.Also I wants to load images using lazy loading as first it iterates over all images and then display in scroll view so it takes more time when there are large number of images.
Also if there is any other link then please post it.
Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: As I was working on this I found solution ,for this but still I am getting error in iphone::FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -12914. 3031040 bytes. We will fall back to software decode.

Comment: any solution to remove this error?